# Google Calendar API per event user access rights

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

We have a shared calendar, which contains numerous events. But the thing is that all the users should have different access rights to each event.

So in the scope of one calendar, each user should attend different events. And the ones which are not attended by a user should be completely invisible to him.

Now we have a situation when an event is marked as private, and the user was not invited – there is a mark `busy` on his calendar without event details. But we don't need any marks in user's calendar when he doesn't attend.

**This is how we set rules for the calendar**

```
$rule = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRule();
    $scope = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRuleScope();

    $scope->setType( 'user' );
    $scope->setValue( 'mail@gmail.com' );
    $rule->setScope( $scope );
    $rule->setRole( 'reader' );
    //$rule->setRole( 'freeBusyReader' );

    $createdRule = $service->acl->insert( $createdCalendar->getId(), $rule );
```

**And this is how we create an event**

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event( array(
        'summary'       => 'Google I/O 2015',
        'location'      => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
        'description'   => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
        'visibility'    => 'private',
        'start'         => array(
            'dateTime' => '2018-02-15T09:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        ),
        'end' => array(
            'dateTime' => '2018-02-15T17:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        ),
        'recurrence' => array(
            'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
        ),
        'attendees' => array(
            array( 'email' => 'mail2@gmail.com' ),
            //array( 'email' => 'mail@gmail.com' ),
        ),
        'reminders' => array(
            'useDefault'    => FALSE,
            'overrides'     => array(
                array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
            ),
        ),
    ));

    $event = $service->events->insert( $calendarId, $event );
```

So we need something like ACL role `none` (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl) but in per-event scope, not the whole calendar.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I think if the API doesn't support it, you'd have implement the restrictions yourself in your PHP code, checking the attendee list for an event before interacting with the API in relation to that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "transparency" parameter for the event should be set as "transparent"

```
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event( array(
    'summary'       => 'Google I/O 2015',
    'location'      => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
    'description'   => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
    'visibility'    => 'private',
    'transparency'  => 'transparent',
    'start'         => array(
        'dateTime' => '2018-02-15T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    ),
    'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2018-02-15T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    ),
    'recurrence' => array(
        'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
    ),
    'attendees' => array(
        array( 'email' => 'mail2@gmail.com' ),
        //array( 'email' => 'mail@gmail.com' ),
    ),
    'reminders' => array(
        'useDefault'    => FALSE,
        'overrides'     => array(
            array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
            array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
        ),
    ),
));

$event = $service->events->insert( $calendarId, $event );
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer as to why this should work?

Comment: Yes. I tested it ))

Comment: That is not a valid explanation. Please try to make your answers useful to other people as well. Note the part in [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that states "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better".